# Пример использования Yii2-Notification

Tags: yii2, уведомления, виджет

Здравствуйте.

Я решил на проекте использовать [виджет уведомлений](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-notifications/).

В описание есть команда установки виджета в композер, настройка конфигурации, создание класса для уведомления и вызов.

Я все это сделал, но честно, не работает и  не понятно.

Может вы работали с этим виджетом?

Можете показать пример использования? К примеру просто всплывающий банер только для пользователя с id = 1, когда он переходит на определенную страницу?

И ещё вопрос:

Как тут происходит отрисовка уведомления?

Пример кода из виджета:

```
namespace app\notifications;

use Yii;
use webzop\notifications\Notification;

class AccountNotification extends Notification
{
const KEY_NEW_ACCOUNT = 'new_account';

const KEY_RESET_PASSWORD = 'reset_password';

/**
 * @var \yii\web\User the user object
 */
public $user;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getTitle(){
    switch($this->key){
        case self::KEY_NEW_ACCOUNT:
            return Yii::t('app', 'New account {user} created', ['user' => '#'.$this->user->id]);
        case self::KEY_RESET_PASSWORD:
            return Yii::t('app', 'Instructions to reset the password');
    }
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getRoute(){
    return ['/users/edit', 'id' => $this->user->id];
}
}
```

Должно вызываться этим кодом:

```
$user = User::findOne(123);

AccountNotification::create(AccountNotification::KEY_RESET_PASSWORD, ['user' => $user])->send();
```

Но я не понимаю его, как я понял он будет вызывать банер на странице '/users/edit'.

Comment: Добрый день. Дополните, пожалуйста, свой вопрос кодом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день.
Если всё настроили(минимальные настройки), то надо в контроллере **UserController**, в действии **edit** дописать недостающие две строки.

```
use app\notifications\AccountNotification;

public function actionEdit()
{

  AccountNotification::create(AccountNotification::KEY_RESET_PASSWORD, ['user' => 1])->send();
  return $this->render('about');
}
```

А в представлении **edit** добавить вывод виджета

```
<div class="header">

     <?php echo \webzop\notifications\widgets\Notifications::widget() ?>

</div>
```

Так же надо применить миграции для этого пакета.

p.s. Код проверил, на нужной странице выводит уведомление. Вам надо только будет подставить везде свои значения.

Comment: А строчка public function getRoute(){
    return ['/users/edit', 'id' => $this->user->id];
} Такая же?

Comment: Нет, я прописывал свой путь, в данном примере он был site/about